# Why is group_by taking too long to compute?

Tags: r, dplyr

`df` is my sample data frame and `df1` is my expected data frame .

```
df<-data.frame(customer=c("x","x","x","x"),
               device_id=c("65efy","57rfyhj","65efy","65efy"),
               duration=c(23,45,56,78))


df1<-as.data.frame(df%>%group_by(customer,device_id) %>%
  mutate(frequency=length(device_id),avg_duration=round(mean(duration),digits = 0))%>%
  select(customer,device_id,frequency,avg_duration)%>%
  distinct())
```

df1 is taking more than 1 hour when df has 2 million rows ! It is too slow . I am simply trying to calculate frequency and avg duration group by customer and device id

Any other way to expedite this process or suggestions to reduce the time taken by `dyplr`?

Comment: Try using `characters` instead of factors. Can't find the question, but this was answered some days ago.

Comment: Try running this: `df%>%
  mutate_if(is.factor,as.character) %>% 
  group_by(grouping_col) %>% 
  summarise_all(length)`.

Comment: Why `mutate/distinct` and not `summarise`? Also, I would end the pipe with `%>% as.data.frame()`, no speed difference but more readable. (`summarise` tests gave me 45%-52% faster and the greater speedups was with larger data sets.)

Comment: @NelsonGon : Tried both options , still taking so long ... Is something wrong with my machine !! its just 2-3 million rows and I have RAM of 240 GB+

Comment: Try using `df %>% group_by(customer,device_id) %>%  summarise(avg_duration = mean(duration) %>% round, frequency = n())`

Comment: The part of your code that takes the longest is `distinct`, if you want better performance use the data.table package. `library(data.table)` and
`setDT(df)[ , .(frequency = .N,avg_duration=round(mean(duration),digits = 0)), by = .(customer, device_id)]`